# Print SSH output line by line instead of everything at once

Tags: python, bash, shell, ssh

Say I have a server at 01.23.456.789 and run the following command:

```
ssh 01.23.456.789 "python3 -c 'import time; print(1); time.sleep(10); print(2);'"
```

It prints `1` and `2` **simultaneously** after `10` seconds. Is there any way to get the individual output immediately, so I would get `1` printed, wait for `10` seconds, and get `2` printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python buffers its outputs. You have to flush the buffer somehow, either from inside python or from outside using `stdbuf -oL`. You can also use `python3 -u` to automatically flush upon `print`.

```
ssh 01.23.456.789 "python3 -uc 'import time; print(1); time.sleep(10); print(2);'"
```